# AngularJS: How to combine drag and drop with mouseenter/mouseleave (without JQuery-UI)

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

[Here](https://github.com/ganarajpr/angular-dragdrop) I found an Angular-style way to drag & drop that works well across scopes (which -I discovered- not all third-party modules do). Traversing scopes is relevant to my little project, as it involves a recursively nested list. You can find my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/crvgturc/). Note that you can pick up a list element, but dropping is not implemented. What *is* implemented is a directive to fold out a list item if you hover your mouse over it for more than 1.2 seconds.

What I am trying to achieve is to have this foldout directive work *only* when the user is dragging a list item, but not in 'normal' (non-dragging) mode, i.e. the reverse of the current behaviour. As it stands, the list items do not respond to any mouse movement at all during dragging. I suppose this has to do with the `preventDefault()` calls in the `ang-drag-drop` module. Moreover, my Angular directive `delay-foldout` doesn't know about the drag mode; how do you tell it that the user is dragging an item?

My reason for not using JQuery-UI is that I think it's rather overkill for this simple effect, and I suspect it must be doable without it. Unfortunately my JS / JQuery skills are limited, and I'm new to AngularJS. So far, experimenting with the module only messed things up 'beyond all recognition' (and to be frank I don't have a clue where to start changing the code). I therefore decided to put the module in the fiddle, so someone can hopefully point out what should be changed in order for the `delay-foldout` directive to work as intended.

Please do not consider this question criticism on the developer of the module, I think he has done quite a good job. It's just that I'm trying to use it in a way it wasn't originally built for, and hoping to learn something in the process.